# Upload file to FTP Server using Indy

Tags: delphi, upload, ftp, indy, lazarus

I am unable to upload a file to my 000webhost.com FTP Server using Indy for Lazarus. I've tested the ftp connectivity with Windows Command Prompt, and it works fine. These are my Settings (IdFTP):

```
IdFTP1.Host:='shabala.com';
IdFTP1.Passive:=True;
IdFTP1.TransferType:=ftBinary;
IdFTP1.Username:='******';
IdFTP1.Password:='******';
IdFTP1.Port:=21;
```

And this is the code which I use to call my TIdFTP component, IdFTP1:

```
IdFTP1.Connect(True);
//IdFTP1.ChangeDir('/Sessions');
IdFTP1.Put(GetCurrentDir+'\'+Token+'.cmd',Token+'.cmd', False);
IdFTP1.Quit;
IdFTP1.Disconnect;
```

where the variable `Token` is declared as:

```
Token: String;
```

When I ran the program for the first time, it kept freezing and I declared a TIdAntiFreeze component to prevent it from freezing.
So, this is what happens now: sometimes the program works fine, but no files are transferred to the server (If I try to repeat the upload, it gives me an EIdAlredyConnected error), and sometimes (if I change the code a bit, nothing extra) it gives me an EIdProtocolReplyError with a strange message. I tried to catch the exception and get my program to display the message, and I've got some strange characters:

> $ £ ï túÁÕÖ îÖõ)€¶K…ÅõÞl%ÇðåÀ¨Á“§pp
>   A¨%˜ßï7!ƒDªÉ[…oˆ_£P*¡°z1K¢H€Î¨ERPö/
>   üðÎƒç±ïpÄ¼ƒÏƒ‹Ò1ì
>   ¿Á{»(g{å¥r…Ž¹öÐ­R_JúÑ¯uBûŸ€Œ Pp6o¯c[JgžÎ¿­Èà¦Ä€VJþz’0è–`BO@T

The response looks like this if formatted correctly:

[image: Strange response]

I couldn't put the formatted text here directly.

The server works absolutely fine, the directories I'm trying to upload to are chmodded to 777, and I've discovered that the file's size (which I want to upload) isn't greater than 3 KBs.

Any ideas?

Comment: By "bugging" I assume you mean "freezing" - since you attempted to use `TIdAntiFreeze` to solve it?

Comment: Yes. The button which the procedure is assigned to remained in "Clicked State". It is a TBCButton (package BGRAControls). Also, the application wasn't responding (If I clicked on the form, it crashed). @JerryDodge

Comment: That is because `TIdFTP` blocks the calling thread while it is busy doing work (as do all of Indy's components).  If the calling thread is the main UI thread, you prevent it from processing new messages in a timely manner, unless you use `TIdAntiFreeze`. Better to move the `TIdFTP` to a worker thread instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The graphics don't matter. TIdAntiFreeze works just fine. That's not my problem. My problem is that I still can't get the upload to work. Moving the TIdFTP component to another thread won't help... And I still have no idea what caused those strange responses. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Don't use `GetCurrentDir()`, it relies on the calling process's *current working directory*, which changes value during the process's lifetime. If the local file is in your app's folder, use `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)` instead. In any case, what you have shown is not an FTP response, and certainly should never appear in an `EIdProtocolReplyError` exception, which makes me wonder if you are actually connected to a real FTP server and not something else.

Comment: And the only way you can get `EIdAlreadyConnected` is if `Connected()` returns true when calling `Connect()`. `Connected()` returns true if `TIdFTP` is actually connected to a server, or if disconnected but there is still unread data in the `IOHandler.InputBuffer` from an earlier connection. Don't call `Quit()`, it is deprecated, just call `Disconnect()` by itself. And if you call `Disconnect()` in reply to a raised exception, clear the `InputBuffer` of unread data: `IdFTP1.Disconnect; if Assigned(IdFTP1.IOHandler) then IdFTP1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau If I'm not connected to the FTP server, then how can I get the EIdAlredyConnected exception? There's no leftover in the `InputBuffer`, I checked it. My greatest problem is that I can't finish the upload procedure. To check where the program hangs on, I created and assigned an OnWorkEnd event with the `ShowMessage('Upload done!');` code inside. The OnWorkEvent is _never_ executed.

Comment: @TheGreenOmega: The *only* way for `EIdAlreadyConnected` to be raised is if `Connected()` returns true when `Connect()` is called (`Connect()` checks `Connected()` internally), and the *only* way for `Connected()` to return true is if the socket is physically connected to a server (or at least a disconnect has not been detected yet) or the `IOHandler` is still open and its `InputBuffer` has unread data. If `OnWorkBegin` is triggered, `OnWorkEnd` is guaranteed to be triggered, unless a deadlock is occurring in between the two events.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Let's consider that the connection is active. I still can't upload files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only way to get `EIdAlreadyConnected` in the code you showed is if you call `Connect()`, then `Put()` or `Quit()` raises an exception bypassing `Disconnect()`, then you call `Connect()` again. As for the `EIdProtocolReplyError`, I can't answer that without seeing the original server response that triggered it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have struggled a bit with Indy Ftp over the years.
At some point I turned to an alternative (free) Ftp client from [OverbyteIcs (click ICS and then click Download ICS-V8.16 (Apr, 2015))](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html).
If you are not against using a freeware package, the following code will do the job:

```
uses
  ...
  OverbyteIcsFtpCli;

procedure FtpUploadFile( 
                             HostName: String; 
                             UserName: String; 
                             Password: String; 
                             UploadFileName: String; 
                             ToHostDir : String );
var
  FTP: TFtpClient;
begin
  FTP := TFtpClient.Create(nil);
  try
    FTP.HostName := HostName;
    FTP.Passive := True;
    FTP.Binary := True;
    FTP.Username := UserName;
    FTP.Password := Password;
    FTP.Port := '21';

    if not FTP.Open then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to connect: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);

    if (not FTP.User) or (not FTP.Pass) then 
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to login: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);

    FTP.HostDirName := ToHostDir;
    if not FTP.Cwd then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to change dir: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);

    FTP.LocalFileName := UploadFileName;
    FTP.HostFileName := ExtractFileName(UploadFileName);

    if not FTP.Put then
      raise Exception.Create('Failed to upload file: ' + FTP.ErrorMessage);
  finally
    FTP.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FtpUploadFile('rubilaxe.hostoi.com',  
                     '******', '******',
                     IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter( 
                          ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) ) +'datafile.zip',
                     '/files'  );
end;
```